# Why won't my tetromino piece fall down the canvas every second?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a Tetris game. I'm able to draw the piece to the canvas. Now I'm trying to get it to fall down with every second. First thing I found online was clearRect() to reset the canvas. But that didn't work and I don't think that's the core issue. I then just decided to loop through and redraw the whole board blank before I drew the piece like this(startgame() runs every second)

```
function startGame() {
    drawBoard();
    block.drawBlock();
    block.y += unit;
}
```

I would think this is enough to make the piece fall.
1st I redraw the board. 2nd I draw the piece. 3rd I change the piece position. So what's going on here?

```js
//-----I had these tetrominos in another file called blocks.js----

const J = [[[1, 0, 0],
            [1, 1, 1],
            [0, 0, 0]],

           [[0, 1, 1],
            [0, 1, 0],
            [0, 1, 0]], 

           [[0, 0, 0],
            [1, 1, 1],
            [0, 0, 1]],

           [[0, 0, 1],
            [0, 0, 1],
            [0, 1, 1]]]

const L = [[[0, 0, 1],
            [1, 1, 1],
            [0, 0, 0]],

           [[0, 1, 0],
            [0, 1, 0],
            [0, 1, 1]], 

           [[0, 0, 0],
            [1, 1, 1],
            [1, 0, 0]], 
            
           [[1, 1, 0],
            [0, 1, 0],
            [0, 1, 0]]]

const O = [[[1, 1],
            [1, 1]]]           

const I = [[[0, 0, 0, 0],
            [1, 1, 1, 1],
            [0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0]],

           [[0, 0, 1, 0],
            [0, 0, 1, 0],
            [0, 0, 1, 0],
            [0, 0, 1, 0]], 

           [[0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0],
            [1, 1, 1, 1],
            [0, 0, 0, 0]], 

           [[0, 1, 0, 0],
            [0, 1, 0, 0],
            [0, 1, 0, 0],
            [0, 1, 0, 0]]] 

const S = [[[0, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 0],
            [0, 0, 0]],
            
           [[0, 1, 0],
            [0, 1, 1],
            [0, 0, 1]]] 
           
const T = [[[0, 1, 0],
            [1, 1, 1],
            [0, 0, 0]],
            
           [[0, 1, 0],
            [0, 1, 1],
            [0, 1, 0]],

           [[0, 0, 0],
            [1, 1, 1],
            [0, 1, 0]],

           [[0, 1, 0],
            [1, 1, 0],
            [0, 1, 0]]] 
           
const Z = [[[1, 1, 0],
            [0, 1, 1],
            [0, 0, 0]],
           
           [[0, 0, 1],
            [0, 1, 1],
            [0, 1, 0]]]



const cvs = document.querySelector('#canvas');
const ctx = cvs.getContext('2d');
const unit = 35;
//collect blocks from blocks.js and assign a color
const Blocks = [[J, 'blue'], 
                [L, 'orange'], 
                [O, 'yellow'], 
                [I, 'cyan'], 
                [S, 'limegreen'], 
                [T, 'purple'], 
                [Z, 'red']]
//create game variable
let game = setInterval(startGame, 1000);
//grab a random block
let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;

//draW BOARD
function drawBoard() {
    for(let y = 0; y < 20; y++) {
        for (let x = 0; x < 15; x++) {
            ctx.strokeStyle = 'white';
            ctx.fillStyle = "black";
            ctx.strokeRect(x * unit, y * unit, unit, unit);
            ctx.fillRect(x * unit, y * unit, unit, unit); 
        }
    }
}
  
//create block object 
class Block {
    constructor(block, color) {
        this.block = block;
        this.color = color;
        this.blockPosition = block[0];
        this.x = 0;
        this.y = 0;
    }

    drawBlock() {
        for(let r = 0; r < this.blockPosition.length; r++) {
            for(let c = 0; c < this.blockPosition[r].length; c++) {
                if(this.blockPosition[r][c] == 0) continue;
                else {
                    ctx.strokeStyle = this.color;
                    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
                    ctx.strokeRect((this.x + c) * unit, (this.y + r) * unit, unit, unit);
                    ctx.fillRect((this.x + c) * unit, (this.y + r) * unit, unit, unit); 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

let block = new Block(Blocks[r][0], Blocks[r][1]);

function startGame() {
    drawBoard();
    block.drawBlock();
    block.y += unit;
}
```

```css
body, html {
    outline: 1px solid red;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: darkgrey;
}



canvas {
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <title>Tetris</title>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="525" height="700"></canvas>
    <script src="js/blocks.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: wait a bit more.. 5 mins from answer xD

Comment: hmm i was 2 mins late.. ur answer is here(well a pointer to it)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when a problem seemed easy at first then turned to be a cluster.. ur going about it the wrong way.. oof speaking to myself too

NOW

```js
var lim=[425,425,425,425,425,425,425,425]//container length-50 for all containers
var elems=document.getElementsByClassName('container')
var toRun=[true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true]
function spawnBlock(i){
  var x=document.createElement('div')
  x.className="animate"
  elems[i].appendChild(x)//if you want each block to be recorded(i suggest you do, for whatever calculations including their place, replace x with an outside object(which would have whatever construct u need for whatever data you need))
  
  if(!toRun[i]){return;}
  var pos=0;toRun[i]=false
  var id=setInterval(()=>{
    if(pos>=lim[i]){
      lim[i]-=55;clearInterval(id)
      if(lim[i]<30){toRun[i]=false}
      else{toRun[i]=true}
    }
    else{pos++;x.style.top=pos+"px"}
  },5)
}
spawnBlock(0)//first block spawn (really as an uncomplicated example)

var s=setInterval(()=>{//blocks will spawn until board is FULL
  var j=Math.floor(Math.random()*lim.length)
  if(toRun[j]){spawnBlock(j)}
  else if(lim.filter(a=>{return a>=30}).length==0){
    console.log("The entire board has been successfully filled")
    clearInterval(s)
  }
},1000)
//the only numbers that were 'fine tuned' were 425,55,30
//425 is roughly container height - animate height
//55 is roughly the spacing between blocks in a row
//30 is roughly what lim[i] would be when filled
//the else if condition in the s interval is the condition for if the board is filled
//now as to if you want to make the spawner shoot only 1 at a time(not just 1 per grid at a time, u can modify the interval to read from some global vars of your design.. not gonna spoonfeed u more.. now i wanna play that game when ur finished xD)
```

```css
.container {
  width: 60px;
  height: 480px;
  position: relative;
  background: yellow;
  float: left;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
}
.animate {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class ="container"></div>
<div class ="container"></div>
<div class ="container"></div>
<div class ="container"></div>
<div class ="container"></div>
<div class ="container"></div>
<div class ="container"></div>
<div class ="container"></div>
```

Seriously, respond in this chat and send me the game link when u made it xD